# Unwanted session files in my php session folder

Tags: php, mysql, apache, session

I am accessing my website from Linux server. At the time of user login I create session.

But Even I didn't open site and locate in folder /var/lib/php/session
there are contentiously some session file are getting created.
I am unable to find from where these files are getting created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After to much research I found that session were getting created from cron files.
I removed session_start call from  cron files.

Answer (score 0):

A session is always created. Your login just assigns the session with an user and the information that he/she/it is authenticated.

Note: Also search engines and robots create sessions on your page.

Answer (score 0):

PHP creates sessions whenever you call session_start()